Why do composer.json files have multiple ^ versions for the same package?
I noticed when looking at composer.json files, I see a lot of instances of the same major version being prefixed by ^. If it means all versions from that number to before the next full version, why include multiple instances?
For example, doesn't ^8.0 include all versions from 8.0 to 8.9?
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0 | ^8.1 | ^8.2"
    }
}


Chances are that they haven't had a chance to test against 8.9 yet.

Why would ^8.0 include 8.9? You're thinking of >=8.0

@Sammitch According to the composer docs, ^8.0 includes all 8.x versions. Or am I understanding it wrong?

You're right. Whoever wrote the code you copied may have had the same misunderstanding as me.

They may have also wanted to make it explicit for newer programmers or ones who don't pay attention to composer versioning, or wanted to make it easy to remove versions later on (even though changing the number works for that, too)

@aynber That's about the only thing that would make sense. I'm not sure if the version standard follows other dependency or package managers.

Did you ask whoever wrote that constraint? How should we know why any other developer wrote it like that?

"php": "^8.0 | ^8.1 | ^8.2": This line denotes the required PHP version. The ^ symbol signifies that the version should be compatible with the specified ranges. The | symbol is used to specify multiple options. In your case, this configuration allows the project to work with PHP versions 8.0.x, 8.1.x, and 8.2.x, but not with PHP 7.x or PHP 9.x.
You may remove other versions from composer.json if all your team members use PHP 8.2.x and on the server you'll have PHP 8.2.x
As notices in composer docs: In older versions of Composer the single pipe (|) was the recommended alternative to the logical OR. Thus for backwards compatibility the single pipe (|) will still be treated as a logical OR.

This doesn't answer the question. You are simply parsing the configuration line, not answering "why was it written like this", which is what the question asks.
